# Domínio apontando para um IP com porta?

Tags: dns, ip, cpanel

No cPanel com um Registro Tipo A eu posso apenas especificar o IP para o qual o domínio deve ser encaminhado, isso vai por padrão redirecionar para a porta 80, mas e se as configurações do destino estiverem rodando numa porta diferente da 80.

Como posso especificar no cPanel um registro que aponte o domínio para o IP : PORTA?

Já tentei criar um Registro tipo SRV mas não funcionou:

```
Name: teste.dominio.com
Priority: 5
Weight: 5
Port: 7070
Target: ip-do-server
```

Answer (score 1):

Zonas DNS são indiferentes ao protocolo dos IPs ao qual relacionam os nomes, aliases, cname, dentre outros.

O que determina a porta a seguir é o software cliente.

Um web browser envia requisições a porta 80 por padrão.

Um cliente ftp requisita a porta 21 por padrão, e assim por diante.

Para o seu caso teria que resolver com proxy (bypass), roteamento ou um simples redirecionamento.

Você configura isso no seu servidor de páginas web (apache, nginx, iis, etc).